# git updating from base branch

Tags: eclipse, git

Sorry this may be a duplicate but I'm having real trouble trying to find the right answer.

Originally I did a fork of https://github.com/Athou/GeekBot

This created https://github.com/david99world/GeekBot

How do I "update" my branch so it's the same as the base revision, similar to a merge up in SVN?  Sorry, this is probably very simple but I'm very new to GIT, is it possible to do this within Eclipse using egit?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a specific revision, then you just need to do:

```
git checkout <revision>
```

If you're familiar with svn, I've found this [web page](http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html) helpful.

Update:

If you want the latest revision, do:

```
git pull <origin> <branch>
```

Comment: ah, no, sorry I know how to do a checkout (that's about as far as my knowledge goes with GIT, but I want to update my branch so it's as up to date as the base revision)

Comment: Ah, so to update my branch I'd do "git pull https://github.com/Athou/GeekBot.git https://david99world@github.com/david99world/GeekBot.git" does that sound right?

Comment: I get fatal: Couldn't find remote ref https

Answer (score 1):

See *Pull in upstream changes* in http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/

Comment: Hi, I did this and now it just replies "Already up-to-date", the first time it did lots of changes so I assume it worked, but the files have stayed the same when I compare them by hand to the changes on github on the original repo

Comment: `git fetch` does only fetch the changes but does not apply them so they won't be directly visible. A `git merge` needs to follow to see the changes in your current branch. In between the two steps you could, in theory, look at the changes before deciding whether to apply them or not.